# How to mock PrismaService for e2e in NestJs?

Tags: jestjs, nestjs, e2e-testing, prisma

I'm usign [nestjs-prisma](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nestjs-prisma) in NestJs and I have in the following import for the prisma module in the app.module, so in every service I can use the [PrismaService](https://github.com/notiz-dev/nestjs-prisma#basic-usage) as the library allows it.

app.module.ts

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { PrismaModule } from 'nestjs-prisma';
import { CategoryModule } from './category/category.module';

@Module({
  imports: [PrismaModule.forRoot({ isGlobal: true }), CategoryModule],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

I want to do a e2e test just for the CategoryModule and need to mock the PrismaService, how can i do that?

Answer (score 1):

You need to mook first of all the PrismaModule and then import in it the PrismaService, here is an example.

category.e2e-spec.ts

```js
import { Test, TestingModule } from '@nestjs/testing';
import { INestApplication } from '@nestjs/common';
import * as request from 'supertest';
import { PrismaModule, PrismaService } from 'nestjs-prisma';
import { CategoryModule } from '../src/category/category.module';

describe('CategoryModule (e2e)', () => {
  let app: INestApplication;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    // Here you have to mock the category funtions that you'll use
    const mockPrismaService = {
      provide: PrismaService,
      useFactory: () => ({
        category: {
          findMany: jest.fn(() => [])
        },
      }),
    };

    // Here is the creation of the module and the definition for the service
    const mockPrismaModule = {
      module: PrismaModule,
      providers: [mockPrismaService],
      global: true,
    };

    const moduleFixture: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      imports: [CategoryModule, mockPrismaModule], // Here is the import for the mock module
    }).compile();

    app = moduleFixture.createNestApplication();
    await app.init();
  });

  it('(GET) /category', () => {
    return request(app.getHttpServer()).get('/category').expect(200);
  });
});
```